# GPU usage of webp on iphone, compared to png

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-x, webp

I am currently working on an iOS game and the image resources seem to be a little too much. I heard of webP and wanted to know more about it.

I did some researches on webP and know that this new format requires much less space than PNG and its encoding/decoding speed is fast. But I found no article discussing the GPU burden when using WebP pictures, compared to PNG ones.

Is there any article out there on this topic?

Or can I do the experiment myself? I am coding in VS using cocos2d-x. I don't know what to do if I want to simulate an iOS GPU and monitor its memory usage.

Many thanks!

Comment: The "less space" means a smaller compressed image file. Once data has been decompressed, it is RGB data and it no longer matters what the compressed size was.

Comment: When using image formats that are software-decoded (first column in [this table](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Texture_Formats_Supported_by_Cocos2d-x?project_id=cocos2d-x)), the decoding of the image occurs on CPU. After it is decoded, the texture can be consumed by GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume that the textures generated remain the same, ie render at the same speed, using the same amount of memory.

If you want faster loading and rendering and less memory usage, use the .pvr.ccz format.